# Ubuntu 20.04 on-sccreen keyboard not hiding automatically

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen

So i recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04
and i am missing (or cannot find) some options for on screen keyboard.
My PC has a touchscreen, and with 18.04 there was a possibility (on X11)
to show on screen keyboard when i touch editable fields AND
automatically hide the keyboard whenever i move my mouse or start typing 
with physical keyboard.

How same can be achieved with Focal?

Thank you!